# Problem with nested quotes in bash: mongodump with query in a docker container via ssh

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker

I'm backing up my database that's in a docker container, and since the total filesize is too large to fit onto the remaining disk space I execute it via SSH and dump it onto my local pc with this command (I'm using Ubuntu default bash):

```sh
docker-machine ssh my-machine-image "docker exec container-id /bin/sh -c 'mongodump --archive -u=admin --authenticationDatabase=admin -p=mongo-pwd --db=my-db --collection=my-collection --gzip'" > myfile.dump
```

This works pretty great, however I'm having trouble getting it to work with the `--query` command. [Mongodump requires it to be in strict JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-query) and I'm having trouble with getting the nested quotes in bash to work. My most successful attempt (aka it actually successfuly executed the command instead of returning a syntax/JSON error) was with a string literal like this, however that seems to parse the JSON wrong, since it always returns 0 documents, no matter the query:

```sh
docker-machine ssh my-machine-image "docker exec container-id /bin/sh -c $'mongodump --archive -u=admin --authenticationDatabase=admin -p=mongo-pwd --db=my-db --collection=my-collection --query=\'{ \"_id\": { \"$oid\": \"some_random_object_id\" } }\' --gzip'" > myfile.dump
```

What is the correct way to pass strict JSON to the `--query` parameter with this amount of nested quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple layers of quoting it would be easiest to assign each layer to a variable. Then use bash's `printf %q` to automatically quote any string for use in a shell.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
json='{"_id": { "'"$oid"'": "some_random_object_id" } }'
cmd="mongodump --archive -u=admin --authenticationDatabase=admin -p=mongo-pwd --db=my-db --collection=my-collection --query=$(printf %q "$json") --gzip"
sshCmd="docker exec container-id /bin/sh -c $(printf %q "$cmd")"

docker-machine ssh my-machine-image "$sshCmd"
```